Regression models that depend on outputs of other regression models
There is a milk factory with the following variables available at the weekly level (i.e. data at the end of each week) and orders are finished on a first in first out basis:

total incoming orders (this week)
total completed orders (this week)
total number of employees (this week)
total hours worked by all employees (this week)
total backlog (this week)
number of spoiled orders in backlog (this week)

I am trying to make a simulation which based on historical data (e.g. 3 years of data), estimates how many spoiled orders will happen in the next 3 months. If there was more granular data, I would have used something like a MMK queue. But since I only have weekly data, I am thinking of use a time series regression approach.
My understanding of the problem is as follows (I tried to use logic to decide what can affect each variable):

incoming orders likely depend on previous incoming orders (i.e.  seasonal)
completed orders likely depend on workers
total hours worked likely depends on previous values of total hours (i.e. seasonal) ... but could also depend on number of previous workers
total workers depends on previous total workers (i.e. seasonal, flu, holidays, etc)
Backlog is more complicated... likely depends on previous backlog, previous completed, previous incoming, previous number of workers, previous hours
spoiled is even more complicated likely depends on previous spoiled, previous backlog previous backlog, previous completed, previous incoming, previous number of workers, previous hours

I thought that for this problem, I could fit multiple ARIMA/ARIMAX models:

Model 1: ARIMA for incoming orders
Model 2: ARIMAX for completed orders
Model 3: ARIMA for total hours worked
Model 4: ARIMA for total workers
Model 5: ARIMAX for backlog
Model 6: ARIMAX for spoiled orders

From here:

I would make a one-step forecast for Model 1, Model 3, Model 4
Use the one-step forecasts from these models to make a one step forecast for Model 5 and Model 2
Use the one-step forecast from Models 2 and 5 for Model 6 and count the forecasted number of spoiled orders
Repeat this process again by updating Models 1,3,4 with their previous forecasts, propagating them forward to count the forecasted number of spoiled orders
Repeat this whole exercise multiple times to get prediction intervals

I thought that the advantage of this approach results in models that can be estimated in isolation and minimize problems relating to simultaneity and endogeneity. This approach can also allow the factory to simulate how many orders would spoil if they deterministically controlled the number of employees in the factory.
Does this approach make sense? (I have included an R simulation below)

library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

n_weeks <- 156

historical_data <- tibble(
    date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2021-01-01"), length.out = n_weeks, by = "week"),
    incoming = rpois(n_weeks, lambda = 1000),
    workers = round(rnorm(n_weeks, mean = 100, sd = 10)),
    hours = NA,
    completed = NA,
    backlog = NA,
    spoiled = NA
)

for(i in 1:n_weeks) {
    historical_data$hours[i] <- historical_data$workers[i] * 40 + rnorm(1, 0, 50)
    historical_data$completed[i] <- rpois(1, lambda = historical_data$hours[i] * 0.2)
    
    if(i == 1) {
        historical_data$backlog[i] <- historical_data$incoming[i] - historical_data$completed[i]
    } else {
        historical_data$backlog[i] <- max(0, historical_data$backlog[i-1] + historical_data$incoming[i] - historical_data$completed[i])
    }
    
    historical_data$spoiled[i] <- rpois(1, lambda = historical_data$backlog[i] * 0.05)
}

generate_all_forecasts <- function(data, horizon = 13) {
    model1 <- auto.arima(data$incoming)
    model2 <- auto.arima(data$completed)
    model3 <- auto.arima(data$hours)
    model4 <- auto.arima(data$workers)
    
    f_incoming <- forecast(model1, h = horizon, level = c(80, 95))
    f_completed <- forecast(model2, h = horizon, level = c(80, 95))
    f_hours <- forecast(model3, h = horizon, level = c(80, 95))
    f_workers <- forecast(model4, h = horizon, level = c(80, 95))
    
    backlog_xreg <- cbind(completed = data$completed, incoming = data$incoming)
    model5 <- auto.arima(data$backlog, xreg = backlog_xreg)
    future_xreg_backlog <- cbind(completed = f_completed$mean, incoming = f_incoming$mean)
    f_backlog <- forecast(model5, xreg = future_xreg_backlog, level = c(80, 95))
    
    spoiled_xreg <- cbind(backlog = data$backlog)
    model6 <- auto.arima(data$spoiled, xreg = spoiled_xreg)
    future_xreg_spoiled <- cbind(backlog = f_backlog$mean)
    f_spoiled <- forecast(model6, xreg = future_xreg_spoiled, level = c(80, 95))
    
    return(list(
        incoming = f_incoming,
        completed = f_completed,
        hours = f_hours,
        workers = f_workers,
        backlog = f_backlog,
        spoiled = f_spoiled
    ))
}

forecasts <- generate_all_forecasts(historical_data)

future_dates <- seq.Date(from = max(historical_data$date) + 7, 
                         by = "week", 
                         length.out = length(forecasts$incoming$mean))

create_forecast_data <- function(historical_data, forecasts, future_dates, var_name) {
    historical <- historical_data %>%
        select(date, !!var_name) %>%
        rename(value = !!var_name) %>%
        mutate(type = "Historical")
    
    forecast_mean <- tibble(
        date = future_dates,
        value = forecasts[[var_name]]$mean,
        type = "Forecast"
    )
    
    forecast_intervals <- tibble(
        date = future_dates,
        lower80 = forecasts[[var_name]]$lower[,1],
        upper80 = forecasts[[var_name]]$upper[,1],
        lower95 = forecasts[[var_name]]$lower[,2],
        upper95 = forecasts[[var_name]]$upper[,2]
    )
    
    list(
        data = bind_rows(historical, forecast_mean),
        intervals = forecast_intervals
    )
}

titles <- c(
    incoming = "Weekly Incoming Orders",
    completed = "Weekly Completed Orders",
    workers = "Total Active Workers",
    hours = "Total Hours Worked",
    backlog = "Current Order Backlog",
    spoiled = "Weekly Spoiled Orders"
)

colors <- c(
    incoming = "#2ecc71",    # Green for incoming
    completed = "#3498db",   # Blue for completed
    workers = "#9b59b6",     # Purple for workers
    hours = "#f1c40f",       # Yellow for hours
    backlog = "#e67e22",     # Orange for backlog
    spoiled = "#e74c3c"      # Red for spoiled
)

variables <- c("incoming", "completed", "workers", "hours", "backlog", "spoiled")
plot_data <- map(variables, ~create_forecast_data(historical_data, forecasts, future_dates, .x))
names(plot_data) <- variables

panel_plot <- map2(plot_data, variables, function(pd, var) {
    ggplot() +
        geom_ribbon(data = pd$intervals,
                    aes(x = date, ymin = lower95, ymax = upper95),
                    fill = colors[var], 
                    alpha = 0.2) +
        geom_ribbon(data = pd$intervals,
                    aes(x = date, ymin = lower80, ymax = upper80),
                    fill = colors[var], 
                    alpha = 0.3) +
        geom_line(data = pd$data,
                  aes(x = date, y = value),
                  color = "black",
                  size = 0.8) +
        geom_line(data = filter(pd$data, type == "Forecast"),
                  aes(x = date, y = value),
                  color = colors[var],
                  size = 0.8) +
        labs(title = titles[var],
             y = "Count",
             x = "") +
        theme_minimal() +
        theme(
            legend.position = "none",
            plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 8),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
        )
}) %>%
    wrap_plots(ncol = 2)

panel_plot + 
    plot_annotation(
        title = "Milk Factory Operations: Historical Data and Forecasts",
        subtitle = "Showing 80% (darker) and 95% (lighter) prediction intervals",
        theme = theme(
            plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5),
            plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5)
        )
    )



As an aside, if you used best R programming practices and minimized the use of tidyverse your code would be much, much cleaner.  In particular excessive use of $ indicates a problem.

The title of your question sounds like "chaining estimators" https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.RegressorChain.html

"Does this approach make sense?" That's quite a long method description. Could you make a more concise specific question. It makes no sense that it is such long. (I am not saying that you remove the long stuff, and it can be helpful to understand details, but it also helps if you have a more shorter to the point specific description of the question. The phrase 'does this approach make sense' is very vague. Especially if it is a long detailed description of an approach.)

ok - so the main point: can i fit individual models and feed the outputs of these models as inputs to other models? does this violate statistical assumptions?


can i fit individual models and feed the outputs of these models as inputs to other models?

Of course you can compute an intermediate statistic. Already something like computing an average or a median is fitting a model. So whoever uses averages as input for a model is feeding output from one model as input to another model.

does this violate statistical assumptions?

There is no clear reason to believe that this violates assumptions.
It depends on a case by case examination. Some assumption could be for instance independence. If each model is fitted independently on independently generated data, then the outputs are also independent. If the outputs are not independent or based on the same data, then the outputs are not independent and you likely violate the independence assumption.
If everything with assumptions is in order, then the main reason why one would not do this two stage modeling is a potential loss of efficiency. An average or output from a model, that might not be a sufficient statistic. A more complex fitting method might give a better, more precise, answer (on the other hand, it can also be computationally complex).
An interesting aspect of a two stage modeling is that it sort of captures an errors in parameters or mixed effects modelling. A mixed effects model would tackle these dual errors more nicely by integrating over the entire space of possibilities (example here: Why do fixed effects in a logistic regression model differ depending on the presence of a random intercept?), but it is not a violation of some assumptions if you don't do this. The effect is that you loose some slight information and your estimates of the variance will be a bit larger (you loose some power).

In your specific example you have these models 5 and 6 that you use for making predictions. The error estimates for these will need to take into account error propagation. Possibly the software doesn't do this and might assume that the features are real observed values instead of estimates.

The idea of using intermediate regression models is as you note definitely condoned in statistics. For example predicted propensity scores as covariates in an RCT regression model.

@jbuddy_13 I didn't mention that it is condoned. I only said that it may lead to results with lower power. And in my comment I noted that you need to account for error propagation (so it can be done as long as you do that). Is that case for the example that you mention?

I tried to reproduce a Pythonic solution to your question similar to the R implementation example you provided but with pandas, statsmodels. It includes ARIMA and ARIMAX models, one-step forecasts, and simulations to estimate the number of spoiled orders. (mostly forecast constant value for next step)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import product
import warnings
from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import ConvergenceWarning # Import ConvergenceWarning from statsmodels

# Suppress the ConvergenceWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=ConvergenceWarning)

# Generate synthetic data
def generate_data(n_weeks):
    np.random.seed(123)
    dates = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01", periods=n_weeks, freq="W")
    incoming = np.random.poisson(1000, n_weeks)
    workers = np.round(np.random.normal(100, 10, n_weeks))
    hours = workers * 40 + np.random.normal(0, 50, n_weeks)
    completed = np.random.poisson(hours * 0.2)
    backlog = np.zeros(n_weeks)
    spoiled = np.zeros(n_weeks)

    for i in range(n_weeks):
        if i == 0:
            backlog[i] = incoming[i] - completed[i]
        else:
            backlog[i] = max(0, backlog[i-1] + incoming[i] - completed[i])
        spoiled[i] = np.random.poisson(backlog[i] * 0.05)

    data = pd.DataFrame({
        "date": dates,
        "incoming": incoming,
        "workers": workers,
        "hours": hours,
        "completed": completed,
        "backlog": backlog,
        "spoiled": spoiled,
    })

    return data

n_weeks = 156
data = generate_data(n_weeks)

# Forecasting functions
def fit_arima(series, order=(1, 0, 0)):
    model = ARIMA(series, order=order)
    fit = model.fit()
    return fit

def fit_arimax(series, exog, order=(1, 0, 0)):
    model = SARIMAX(series, exog=exog, order=order)
    fit = model.fit(disp=False)
    return fit

def forecast_with_models(data, horizon=13):
    forecasts = {}

    # Fit ARIMA for incoming, workers, and hours
    forecasts["incoming"] = fit_arima(data["incoming"]).forecast(horizon)
    forecasts["workers"] = fit_arima(data["workers"]).forecast(horizon)
    forecasts["hours"] = fit_arima(data["hours"]).forecast(horizon)

    # Fit ARIMAX for backlog and completed orders
    backlog_exog = data[["completed", "incoming"]]
    backlog_model = fit_arimax(data["backlog"], backlog_exog)
    future_exog_backlog = pd.DataFrame({
        "completed": forecasts["incoming"],  # Assuming 'completed' is related to 'incoming' for forecasting
        "incoming": forecasts["workers"]   # Assuming 'incoming' is related to 'workers' for forecasting
    })
    forecasts["backlog"] = backlog_model.forecast(horizon, exog=future_exog_backlog)
    
    # Fit ARIMA for completed orders - Added this section to forecast 'completed'
    forecasts["completed"] = fit_arima(data["completed"]).forecast(horizon)


    # Fit ARIMAX for spoiled orders
    spoiled_exog = data[["backlog"]]
    spoiled_model = fit_arimax(data["spoiled"], spoiled_exog)
    future_exog_spoiled = pd.DataFrame({
        "backlog": forecasts["backlog"]
    })
    forecasts["spoiled"] = spoiled_model.forecast(horizon, exog=future_exog_spoiled)

    return forecasts

forecasts = forecast_with_models(data)

# Generate future dates
future_dates = pd.date_range(start=data["date"].iloc[-1] + pd.Timedelta(weeks=1),
                             periods=13, freq="W")

# Plot forecasts
def plot_forecasts(data, forecasts, future_dates):
    variables = ["incoming", "workers", "hours", "completed", "backlog", "spoiled"]
    titles = [
        "Weekly Incoming Orders", "Total Active Workers", "Total Hours Worked",
        "Weekly Completed Orders", "Current Order Backlog", "Weekly Spoiled Orders"
    ]

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

    for i, var in enumerate(variables):
        plt.subplot(3, 2, i + 1)
        plt.plot(data["date"], data[var], label="Historical", color="blue")
        plt.plot(future_dates, forecasts[var], label="Forecast", color="orange")
        plt.title(titles[i])
        plt.legend()
        plt.xticks(rotation=45) # Rotate x-ticks by 45 degrees
        plt.tight_layout()
    
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9) # Adjust the top margin to make space for the suptitle
    plt.suptitle("Milk Factory Operations: Historical Data and Forecasts", fontsize=16)
    plt.show()

plot_forecasts(data, forecasts, future_dates)

now your Qs:

Does this approach make sense?

Yes, this approach makes sense for the given problem. It uses sequential modeling to predict interdependent variables, leveraging ARIMA and ARIMAX models to isolate relationships between variables while avoiding simultaneity and endogeneity issues particularly suited to the weekly data you have due to the lack of more granular data.
Side note: Be aware that ARIMA and ARIMAX assume linear relationships, which might not fully capture complex dependencies. Furthermore, Weekly-level aggregated data might obscure finer dynamics that more granular data could capture.
Of course, ARIMA and ARIMAX are valid choices for this kind of time series forecasting when historical dependencies and relationships between variables are the main focus.

"ARIMA: is fine for uni-variate time series with trends or seasonality."
"ARIMAX: this is an extension of ARIMA by including external regressors, which makes it ideal for capturing the influence of one variable on another (e.g., backlog influenced by completed and incoming orders)".


"I thought that the advantage of this approach results in models that can be estimated in isolation and minimize problems relating to
simultaneity and endogeneity. This approach can also allow the factory
to simulate how many orders would spoil if they deterministically
controlled the number of employees in the factory."

Let's break it down:

Does this approach minimize problems related to simultaneity and endogeneity?

Yes, sure. This sequential approach effectively minimizes problems of simultaneity and endogeneity by modeling independent variables first and using their forecasts as inputs for dependent variables. This approach also minimizes simultaneity and endogeneity issues by isolating causal relationships.

Can this approach simulate control scenarios like adjusting worker numbers?

This approach supports scenario simulations by allowing deterministic changes in inputs like worker numbers to assess their downstream impact on backlog and spoiled orders.

Note: If there's a seasonal component (e.g., higher orders during holidays), consider SARIMA/SARIMAX or adding seasonal dummy variables in ARIMAX. Alternatively, consider machine learning models (e.g., Random Forests, Gradient Boosting) if relationships are highly non-linear.

Your reproduction in python doesn't include the linear model. The forecasts for the backlog and spoiled orders are constant values without a trend.

I mentioned this in my post: "..(mostly forecast constant value for next step)" due to ARIMA and ARIMAX models needing to be tried with different setups! I also believe it could be due to how I generated synthetic data, which could not be perfectly decomposed time-elements. OP can adjust himself.
